# Wordpress, make the breadcrumb recall title h1value of the page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have a wordpress website where I am using Yoast Seo to build the breadcrumb.

My website is currently translated in 6 languages, and all pages have titles like this:

- HELLO (IT), HELLO (UK), HELLO (DE), etc...
  Doing that, I can recognize the content for all languages, but when I build the breadcrumb I get this result:

Home > Hello (it)

And this is not nice.

With Yoast Seo I have the possibility to add a customized page title to display in the breadcrumb, by adding this code:

```
            <?php
                if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
                  yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>' );
                }
        ?>
```

into the page.php, but in this case I have to edit all pages of the website (almost 1000...!!!). Huge work!

So, I am asking if there is a possibility that the breadcrumb call the value of title  of the page to display in the breadcrumb.

Do you think it is possible? I am not good in coding...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Filippo B.